# Symfony: Sonata Admin Bundle Dropdown with Parent and child levels

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am using Sonata admin bundle in my project, i want to populate the dropdown like below,

```
<select>
   <option>Category father-1</option>
   <option>--Category child-1-1</option>
   <option>--Category child-1-2</option>
   <option>--Category child-1-3</option>
   <option>----Category child-1-3-1</option>
   <option>----Category child-1-3-2</option>
   <option>--Category child-1-4</option>
   <option>--...</option>
   <option>Category father-2</option>
</select> `
```

below is my modelAdmin.php code

```
    $formMapper->with('General')
            ->add('name', null, array('required' => true))
            ->add('parent', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'required' => false,
                'class' => 'HUI\PortalBundle\Entity\Category'
            ));
    $formMapper->end()
            ->with('Meta', array('collapsed' => true))
            ->add('status', null, array('required' => false))
            ->end();

    if ($this->getSubject()->getCreatedAt()) {
        $formMapper->with('System Information', array('collapsed' => true))
                ->add('created_at', 'datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'attr' => array('read_only' => true, 'disabled' => true)))
                ->end();
    }
```

but in my case i get all the list without parent-child levels.